# Box2D/LibGDX ContactListener confusion

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

```
public class Test {

M_ContactListener m_contactListener = new M_ContactListener();

public Test(World world)
{
    world.setContactListener(m_contactListener);
}

class M_ContactListener implements ContactListener {
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        System.out.println("touch");
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        System.out.println("touch");
    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

    }
}
```

So I'm wondering why contacts are never being called. I am stepping the world, I have a player I control which is moving around the level, jumping on platforms etc. But no contact is being registered.

I tried setting filter data group index on bodies to the same value but...I have no clue if I'm supposed to be doing that.

My thinking was if two bodies contacted then these methods would be called, which I had working at some point but I can't seem to reproduce it

edit:
tried creating the class on it's own, no difference
am I suppose to be calling something? I wasn't before and it was working..

Comment: Ah, how stupid of me. I had a class initialized that already had its own ContactListener, which I had forgotten about

Comment: So you solved your problem on your own? If so, please post an answer and accept it, so that the question appears as solved.